# Tiling algorithm for recalculation position of vertexes

Tags: c#, algorithm, graphics, 2d

I'm searching for an algorithm for recalculation position of vectors which defines polygon which represents one tile. 
 
I have pattern of tile — a polygon defined by 16 vertices which are in field of vertices.
For example, I have a square (or rhombus or any other polynom which can fit together with the same polygon).

```
x - x - x - x - x
|               |
x               x
|               |
x               x
|               |
x               x
|               |
x - x - x - x - x
```

This pattern represents one tile. If I move with one vertex (change its position), I have to recalculate position of other vertex in order to have tile which fit together with other tiles.  
**1)Does any algorithm exist which already solves that?**  
**2)What is a good basic pattern? Square is too simple.** 
I heard that is good to have symmetric shapes for patterns, cause it's easier to recalculate it.

Edit:
Motivation is to draw tiles on some bitmap. It's like tiles in your bathroom, they must also fit together.

Comment: Sorry, what?  Why can't you just move every vertex in the same direction by the same amount?

Comment: Cause reason for moving one vertex is to change the shape ;)

Comment: So, you're asking if there's an algorithm to determine if a particular set of tiles can tile the plane?  I think you're going to be sorely disappointed...

Comment: Or, every tile has the same shape, and you alter one edge, and you want to know how to alter the other edges to keep it tiled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question:  You start out with a square that passes through some vertices (horizontally- and vertically-symmetric) that you use for tiling.  You move some of those vertices around, and want to know how to keep the resulting-shape tiled?

In that case, **every time you move a vertex, move the vertically-and-horizontally-mirrored vertex in the same direction by the same amount.**

For example, if you move the lower-right vertex down 2 and right 1, you should also move the upper-left vertex down 2 and right 1.  This will create a "hole" in the upper-left that snugly fits the new pointy edge in the lower-right.

Answer (score 0):

On basic tile-able shapes:

Square and rectangle, hexagon are good basic tile-able shapes.

Equilateral triangles are tile-able, but need to be flipped.

There are also more complicated patterns where tiles are not identical. I.e. octagon + square.